# snap, cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_hkxDCG//dev: No such file or directory

Tags: mount, snap

I made an app that I want to publish to the snap store using snapcraft. I have the following yaml file.

```
version: '1.0'
summary: A Tetris clone written in C++
description: |
  A minimal Tetris game written to run in a standard 80x24 terminal. (https://github.com/MitchelPaulin/CTris)

grade: stable # must be 'stable' to release into candidate/stable channels
confinement: devmode # use 'strict' once you have the right plugs and slots
base: core18

parts:
  ctris:
    plugin: make 
    source-type: git
    source: https://github.com/MitchelPaulin/CTris
    build-packages: [libncurses5-dev, libncursesw5-dev, g++, make]

apps:
  ctris:
    command: ../bin/ctris
```

When I type `snapcraft` everything builds and I get an executable in `/snap/bin`. When I try to run it I get the following error.

```
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_hkxDCG//dev: No such file or directory
```

`/tmp/snap.rootfs_hkxDCG` does exist so I am not sure whats going on here.

Comment: you seem to be missing `/dev` in the snap environment (the one under `/tmp/snap.rootfs_hkxDCG`), you can try creating `/dev` alongside `make` or rebasing on an existing image, like alpine or ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

try running `snap list --all` and look for 'broken' 'core packages'. If you find any try removing and re-installing.. that should fix it

Comment: Yep, this is what unstuck my broken Spotify package. Cheers mate.